# PHP date strtotime not working

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I wrote this piece of code

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime($date, strtotime("+ " . $days . " days")));

$date = 2012-04-12
$days = 15
```

I am looking to add `$days` (15 days) to the date (`2012-04-12`) I am expecting to get `2012-04-27` and this code returns me `2012-04-12`, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+15 days', strtotime('2012-04-12')));
```

Answer (score 5):

Don't use strtotime(). It's unreliable, though you're not really doing anything that would really come back to bite you in the rump. But depending on strtotime is still a bad thing, because it WILL make your life miserable at some point.

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php) instead:

```
$now = DateTime::CreateFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2012-04-12');
$then = $now->add(new DateInterval('P15D'));
$date = $then->format('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: `strtotime()` is not unreliable; in fact, DateTime class uses it under the sheets.

Comment: Yeah, if you're the auto-detection stuff. But if you've got a known-format date, then don't use strtotime at all.

Comment: I agree with you in principle, Marc, but I question the necessity of instantiating an object to do something so trivial. If he were going to be doing timezone changes or other more advanced operations, yeah use the object, absolutely. To simply add a few days? Meh.

Answer (score 2):

```
$date = '2012-04-12';
$days = 15;
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$date +$days days") );
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime("+$days days", $date));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is incorrect. It isn't necessary or even helpful to place your code all on one line. In this case, we see that trying to do so causes syntax problems. Don't be afraid of a couple of extra little variables!

```
$date = '2012-04-12';
$days = 15;

$ts = strtotime($date);
$new_ts = strtotime('+'.$days.' days', $ts);
$new_date = date('Y-m-d', $new_ts);
```

Clear, easy to read, easy to debug. If you like code golf, you CAN put it in one line, but there's a clearer way to write it:

```
$new_date = date (
    'Y-m-d',
    strtotime (
        '+'.$days.' days',
        strtotime($date)
    )
);
```

**Documentation**

- PHP's `strtotime` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
- PHP's `date` - http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class?

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->add(new DateInterval('P15D'));
```